# Changing the h:message JSF standard error message

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

We are trying to alter the standard JSF error message that is output by the  tag to not include the JSF rendered ID of the element. So for example:

> j_id1840598516_6db54dbe:terms: Validation Error: Value is required.

to look like:

> terms: Validation Error: Value is required.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UIInput` component's `label` attribute. E.g.

```html
<h:inputText ... label="terms" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use h:outputLabel value attribute, consequently you need type it twice.

Comment: @Gilbertoca: That's exactly why OmniFaces `<o:outputLabel>` exist.